# Regex to match end-of-sentence markers

Tags: java, regex

I need to match all the end-of-sentence symbols like `!`, `?`, `.` (period), etc. in a given body of text.

Can anyone help me out with the regex for doing such a thing?

Example Input:

```
This is the f!!rst sentence! Is this the second one? The third sentence is here... And the fourth one!!
```

Output:

```
This is the f!!rst sentence Is this the second one The third sentence is here And the fourth one
```

Comment: While asking any question, please keep in mind to give sample input and expected output. This will prevent answers solely based on assumptions.

Comment: What have you investigated and tried already?

Comment: People will help you if you ask a question that's useful to more than just you. Which is not the case here.

Comment: Sorry, I was in a bit of a hurry as I needed this for a my University project, basically I am building a search engine prototype and I need to tokenize each word in the data source which contains 10,000+ news articles. One of the tasks of filtering is to remove symbols like !,?,. which occur at the end of sentences as markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[!?.]+(?=$|\s)
```

Try this.You can add markers as needed.Replace by ``.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/15

Comment: Exactly what I wanted! Thank you. By the way, can you recommend a good way to learn reg expressions? I need to master this stuff sooner or later, so I need a good place where I can start from

Comment: @user2306772 see your exmaple.you have removed everything from middle as well.correct it first.

Comment: Hope the question is clear now!

Comment: Ok, Ive probably had a little too much Red Bull to drink... Sorry again!

Comment: @user2306772 why are `?` and '.' between your string missing?

Comment: @user2306772 this doesnt seem to be red bull.Should be some beer :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably want to match anything (.*?) followed by the end of sentence followed by whitespace (\s+). Since !, ? and . are special characters, you'll need to excape them.

eg

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)[\\!\\?\\.]\\s+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("one two. three! four five? ");
while (matcher.find()) {
   System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

prints

```
one two
three
four five
```

Comment: This answer isn't particularly helpful to anyone. The question itself isn't clear.

Comment: Seriously? I think I've explained enough to get the brain thinking. Next time I won't bother.

Comment: I probably screwed up by asking the question in a very casual manner. I was in a hurry and needed some quick help, and didnt bother elaborating much. Anyways, I have made an edit. Lance Java, your answer was certainly helpful, but I suppose that is not what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The below regex would match the non-word characters (except spaces) which must be followed by a space character or end of the line anchor. `replaceAll` function helps to remove all the matched characters.

```
String s = "Blah! blah? blah... blah blah!!";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[^\\w\\s]+(?=\\s|$)", ""));
```

Output:

```
Blah blah blah blah blah
```

If you want to remove only `?`, `.`, `!`  characters which was present at the last in a word, you could try the below code.

```
String s = "This is the f!!rst sentence! Is this the second one? The third sentence is here... And the fourth one!!";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("[!?.]+(?=\\s|$)", ""));
```

**Output:**

```
This is the f!!rst sentence Is this the second one The third sentence is here And the fourth one
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! Both vks' solution and your's worked just fine!

Comment: @user2306772 you did not try the edited one

Comment: @vks i posted the answer before your edit. See the revisions.

Comment: @AvinashRaj the question kept on changing.

Comment: Sorry for the mess! Next time around, I should spend some time elaborating on the question more clearly