# Java Regex to detect end of sentence BUT ignore (num)(period) e.g. 15

Tags: java, regex, sentence

Trying to find a good regex for sentence end detection in java. 
The main issue is if there is a number then period, it detects it as a sentence end (see demo link).  But in my case, I'd prefer it to not recognize that as a sentence end, even though in some cases it might be. What I see in documents more commonly are section headers which look like :

```
  12.  the end of the world   13. world didnt end  14. nope it did
```

In my case it's splitting up a lot of simple header listings into sentences which I don't want.

addition issue with solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25990222/regex-to-match-end-of-sentence-markers):

The proposed solution is:
         [!?.]+(?=$|\s)

```
See demo:  http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/15
```

The issue is if there is a chapter heading such as *15.*  then it sees it incorrectly as a sentence end. 
try this text in the demo and you will see the issue in the first sentence :

```
   This is the f!!rst *15.* the best sentence! Is this the second one? The third 32.5 sentence is here... And the fourth one!!
```

If there are any regex whizzes who can help add logically that it is not a sentence end if period space but preceeded by a number that would be quite helpful

Comment: Use a negative lookbehind that matches a digit.

Comment: I tried to improve your quesiton formatting, but then you undid it with your next edit. Please fix it yourself now.

Comment: You will also have to account for common abbreviations like `Dr.`, `U.S.`, etc.

Comment: And account for names with initial for middle name, like `John F. Kennedy`

Comment: @Barmar  OK I am done now. sorry for undoing your obviously needed assist   yes I added lookbehind. please forgive my weak regex

Comment: @FredK  yes I have tested with Dr.  U.S.  and John F. Kennedy

Comment: How does it work checking these two sentences: `His first name and initial are John F. Kennedy was the 35th president.`

Answer (score 0):

This regex works with some of the abbreviations and correctly recognizes the sentence end markers.  Unfortunately, for java string.split I would need the inverse of this function...

```
 ([!?]+(?=$|\s))|((?<![\d])(?<!etc)(?<!Mr)(?<!mr)(?<!i.e)(?<!Dr)(?<!dr)(?<!Mrs)(?<!mrs)(?<![ A-Z])(?<!Ms)(?<!ms)(?<!Phd)(?<!u\.s)(?<!U\.S)(?<!\.)[.]{1}(?=$|\s))|
```